# Assign output of powershell command to variable

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-interface

I am struggling to be able to run a command and attach to variable in windows!

On mac I would run:

```
export TOKEN="$(curl --header "Metadata-Flavor: Google" --get --data-urlencode "audience=http://vault/${ROLE}" --data-urlencode "format=full" "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity")"
```

But struggling to run same on windows (have tried piping output using `>` but no luck)!

What am I obviously missing!

Comment: What Powershell command?

Comment: To assign something to a variable you just need to do this: `$Variable = "my something"`.

Comment: Great question! Really any of them, but was using choco installed curl - so that same curl command! 
Like the output of the command not the command itself.

Comment: Please have a look at [about_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.1) pages

Comment: Also, instead of curl try using PowerShell [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet

Answer (score 6):

You can assign the output of any command in PowerShell by just using this syntax.

```
$myNewVar = hostname #or any other command
```

What will happen is that the output of the command is consumed and stored in the variable, so nothing gets output to the screen.

if you want to assign a variable while also outputting to the screen, us the `Tee` command.

```
hostname | tee-object -variable myNewVar
```

Comment: Nice, but note the `export` in the OP's command, so it's worth showing `$env:myNewVar = ...`